# git autocrlf setting set to true yet having unexpected results when staging files, commiting and checkingout

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have read so much about the config setting core.autocrlf and what you can set it to. Yet I am having a lot of problem understanding why it doesn't work the way I expected it to.

- **Machine I'm working on:** Windows
- **Experience with git:** Beginner
- **Terminal:** git bash
- **core.autocrlf**: true

So let's begin with the first bit of confusion. I used the command `echo hello > file1.txt` in my working directory, then I also created a text file by opening notepad and saving it in the same location as my "file1.txt" and giving it the name "file_windows.txt". When opening both files on notepad, I saw a difference, "file1.txt" had "Unix (LF)" marked at the bottom of the notepad tab, whereas "file_windows.txt" had "Windows (CRLF)". I imagine the distinction was made since the first file was made with a unix/linux command in comparison to the other file which was created through the use of notepad and windows.

Now the problem arises when I tried adding those files to the staging area. When using the command `git add file1.txt`, I was faced with the following message:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file1.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

I was a bit shocked since I thought that having `core.autocrlf` set to true would mean that git would make changes to the file by making sure "crlf" was replaced with "lf" when adding to the staging area, not the other way round suggested by the warning, of course the point of having that setting on was so that if let's say for example, someone on a linux platform with `core.autocrlf` set to false, would be able use that git repository without having to worry about some file having "crlf" instead of "lf".

Then when using the command `git add file_windows.txt` there would be no warnings as expected, since I imagine it is doing what it is supposed to do and replace "crlf" with "lf" when adding it to the staging area. What I am trying to get at here is that if there was for some reason to be a file that I'm working with that is in "lf", I wouldn't want it then switching it to "crlf" when I am adding it to the staging area, since there really wouldn't be a need to do so and it would probably not be beneficial.

Another thing to mention is that (although shouldn't be taken too seriously since I am a beginner using git so I don't know if it is because I am doing something wrong) when I commit both files, then use the command `git checkout <commit hash>` and then go open the files by `start file1.txt` (which opens them up on a notepad), I don't end up seeing the change which the warning stated it would make, it still shows as "Unix (LF)" and not "crlf" so it leaves me even the more confused.

Coudl someone explain what is going on please?

Comment: Notepad is likely the only remaining program that needs CR-LF endings.  Is it still limited to 64K files?

Comment: @stark I really have no clue, since I don't even use notepad that often but in this case I used it to test with git

Answer (score 0):

The warning "LF will be replaced by CRLF in file1.txt" means that it will be replaced by CRLF when you check the file out next.  The file is indeed stored with LF endings in the repository, since all files subject to text handling are stored that way.

However, when you use `git checkout`, Git doesn't check out files which are up to date in the index.  That's why you don't see `git checkout` modifying the files in the working tree.

This message is ultimately harmless, but it just warns you that you've placed a file into the working tree that does not use the line endings that you've requested, explicitly or implicitly, which means you may end up with different behavior next time you clone or checkout the repository.  If all your tools handle any line ending gracefully, or you've properly configured your `.gitattributes` file to specify appropriate line endings, then you shouldn't have anything to worry about.